# Localized relative date formatting in Java

Tags: java, date, time, localization

I would like to display dates like this:

> [RELATIVE], SHORT-MONTH DAY YEAR HOURS:MINS [AM|PM] [TIMEZONE]

For Locale.ENGLISH e.g.:

```
Today, Jan 26, 2012 07:41 PM CET
```

For Locale GERMAN e.g.:

```
Heute, 26. Jan 2012 19:41 MEZ
```

For a date several days ago just:

```
Jan 22, 2012 07:41 PM CET
```

So, the [RELATIVE]-"prefix" should only appear if "available" (using ICU4J), otherwise we would like to see the exact date; we want do switch from a 12/24 hours representation automatically based on the locale

Patterns do not work since there is no identifier for that relative thing and also none for hh:mm with automatic 12/24 hours based on the locale.

Any idea?

Comment: Is there something specific you're asking for help with, or just writer's block?

Comment: I am asking for a piece of code which returns a String containing the date and time in the above mentioned representation based on a date and locale being handed-over.

Comment: Oh, so it's a "do my work for me" question.

Comment: No, it was a question and I thought forums are intended for asking questions; maybe a hint would have been helpful alrady -  but I just found out how to do it... thanks for nothing :)

Comment: I'm not really trying to antagonise you. Regardless of whether you like it or not, questions that are essentially "send me the codez" aren't, I'd say, very welcome on SO. "Not very welcome" meaning that you're unlikely to get the answer you want, and will ultimately have wasted time waiting for one. On the other hand, making questions people want to answer is a win-win situation.

Comment: Also, standard boilerplate: SO is not a forum, but a QA site with a narrow scope. Not every question that has to do with writing code is a "good" SO question. (The FAQ, the blog, and the meta site are probably better qualified than me to explain what does indeed make a good SO question and who decides this.)

Comment: And the final question: how did you solve this? For the next ones who will run into the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at

```
DateFormat.getDateInstance(int style, Locale locale)
```

[Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.6.0/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html)

With this you can get locale dependent format strings. I'm not aware of any proper API to provide Today/Tomorrow - Heute/Morgen in front of your date. But you could easily provide the day of week in front, like Wed 01/01/2010 10:00PM.

DateFormat supports both, 12 with AM/PM or 24 hours a day.

---

Update to your comment: Check the javadoc again, DateFormat supports AM/PM or full hours of day depending on locale.

```
    System.out.println(DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.FULL,
            DateFormat.FULL, Locale.ENGLISH).format(
            Calendar.getInstance().getTime()));
    System.out.println(DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.FULL,
            DateFormat.FULL, Locale.GERMAN).format(
            Calendar.getInstance().getTime()));
```

generates

```
Thursday, January 26, 2012 9:49:41 PM CET
Donnerstag, 26. Januar 2012 21:49 Uhr MEZ
```

Leaves the today/tomorrow issue. SimpleDateFormat does not provide this feature. If you really need it, I'd write a helper that takes the input parameters, wraps the getDateTimeInstance().format() call and adds Today/Tomorrow in front of it, if the date matches.

Comment: I know, but that is not what I want; I do want one specification with which I get Today/Tomorrow at the beginning and not the day of the week (that would be easy) and also an automatic detection of the correct hours format (12/24) dep. on the locale...

Comment: I've updated my post: Dateformat already detects the hours format, see the example.

Comment: Argh, yes, it does if you do not work with patterns, I know. I already was at that point. But it is not trivial to do a localized prefixing with a relative date - how do you want to do that cross languages?

Comment: Well, then I would redo what ICU4J already does, they provide translated prefixed for relative dates already; even better: the behavior is different for different locales. For German e.g. they even support vorgestern (the day before yesterday), for English only yesterday is supported. Finding all translations for all ~30 languages and ~5 relative dates per language does not sound the right approach.

Comment: Sorry, missed the ICU4J part.